# How do I unlock the background in Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I unlock the background in Photoshop CS5?

Answer (score 2):

Right click the Background on the Layers panel and select "Layer from background..."

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

My image was in `bitmap mode` and when I changed it to `grayscale mode` I could then doubel-click on the backgroundlayer and create a layer from it.

Perhaps changing your image mode could do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to turn the background into a normal layer is to just Double Click on it.

[image]

Then click "OK" when the window appears...

[image]

Comment: have tried that.. but it doesn't work.. it worked in all previous versions but not in CS5

Comment: @clarkk, I currently used CS5, too. (As you can probably tell from the images.) Strange that it's not working for you, as it does for me. What OS are you using? Perhaps you're not double-clicking fast enough?